# Prevent update to an attribute?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a column that I want to lock after creation i.e. no updates to that column.

First off I know I can lock it down through the form but anyone can pass it through the URL.

I know I could build some sort of check in the update method to compare before and after the update.  I can also add some conditional to the permitted parameters.

I was hoping that it could be a simple addition to the model.  The more simple the better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [attr_readonly](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ReadonlyAttributes/ClassMethods.html#method-i-attr_readonly):

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_readonly :your_field_name
end
```